# Notify PropertyChangeListener faster

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar, propertychangelistener

So I'm creating a JProgressBar that displays the progress of a CSV manipulation, where every line is read and checked if there are no null values in obligatory (*NOT NULL*) columns. For that, I've created a SwingWorker Task that handles converting the number of lines in the file to 100% on the maximum progress value, and adding up on the progress on the correct rate.

That's the SwingWorker:

```
public static class Task extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {

    private int counter;
    private double rate;

    public Task(int max) {
        // Adds the PropertyChangeListener to the ProgressBar
        addPropertyChangeListener(
             ViewHandler.getExportDialog().getProgressBar());
        rate = (float)100/max;
        setProgress(0);
        counter = 0;
    }

    /** Increments the progress in 1 times the rate based on maximum */
    public void step() {
        counter++;
        setProgress((int)Math.round(counter*rate));
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground() throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void done() {
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
      System.out.println("Progress done.");
    }
}
```

My `PropertyChangeListener`, **which is implemented by the JProgressBar wrapper**:

```
@Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
```

Then, where I actually use it, I override the `doInBackground()` method with the processing I need, calling `step()` on every iteration.

```
    Task read = new Task(lines) {
        @Override
            public String doInBackground() throws IOException {
                while(content.hasNextValue()) {
                step();
                // Processing
            }
            return output.toString();
        }
   };
   read.execute();
   return read.get();
```

**So what is happening**: the processing works and succeeds, then `done()` is called, and just after that the `propertyChange()` registers two 'state' events and one 'progress' event, setting the ProgressBar's progress from 0% to 100%.

<strike>What is happening</strike> **What I thought was happening** ([check Hovercraft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672767/9629238) for clarification) is described in the JavaDocs:

*Because PropertyChangeListeners are notified asynchronously on the Event Dispatch Thread multiple invocations to the setProgress method might occur before any PropertyChangeListeners are invoked. For performance purposes all these invocations are coalesced into one invocation with the last invocation argument only.*

So, after all that, **my question is**: am I doing something wrong? If not, is there a way for me to make the Event Dispatch Thread notify the PropertyChangeListeners as the onProgress() happens, or at least from time to time?

*Obs.: the processing I'm testing takes from 3~5s.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
read.execute();
return read.get();
```

`get()` is a blocking call, and so calling it from the event thread immediately after executing your worker will block the event thread **and your GUI**.

Instead, it should be called from a call-back method such as the `done()` method or from the property change listener after the worker has changed its state property to `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`.

---

For example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestSwingWorkerGui extends JPanel {
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    private Action myAction = new MyAction("Do It!");

    public TestSwingWorkerGui() {
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true); 
        add(progressBar);
        add(new JButton(myAction));
    }

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        public MyAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myAction.setEnabled(false);
            Task read = new Task(30) {
                @Override
                public String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    int counter = getCounter();
                    int max = getMax();
                    while (counter < max) {
                        counter = getCounter();
                        step();
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                    }
                    return "Worker is Done";
                }
            };
            read.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropListener());
            read.execute();
        }
    }

    private class MyPropListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String name = evt.getPropertyName();
            if ("progress".equals(name)) {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
            } else if ("state".equals(name)) {
                if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                    myAction.setEnabled(true);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    SwingWorker<String, Void> worker = (SwingWorker<String, Void>) evt.getSource();
                    try {
                        String text = worker.get();
                        System.out.println("worker returns: " + text);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestSwingWorkerGui mainPanel = new TestSwingWorkerGui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class Task extends SwingWorker<String, Void> {

    private int counter;
    // private double rate;
    private int max;

    public Task(int max) {
        // Adds the PropertyChangeListener to the ProgressBar
        // addPropertyChangeListener(gui);
        // !!rate = (float)100/max;
        this.max = max;
        setProgress(0);
        counter = 0;
    }

    /** Increments the progress in 1 times the rate based on maximum */
    public void step() {
        counter++;
        int progress = (100 * counter) / max;
        progress = Math.min(100, progress);
        setProgress(progress);
        // setProgress((int)Math.round(counter*rate));
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
      System.out.println("Progress done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my ProgressBar wrapper  implements PropertyChangeListener, so that's why I was listening to that. But I was looking at the problem from the wrong side, removing the "read.get();" from "return" actually solved my problem! I didn't realize it was blocking my whole application and the GUI. Thank you!

Comment: @MateusW.: you're welcome. My bad about the property change bit, but you should not have your GUI classes implement your listener interfaces. Keep things separate and clean. Note my [mcve] example above.